# How to expose a dependency of a dependency in a maven project

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a maven web application that is using a jar I created and is referenced as a dependency in my pom file.

The jar file I created has another jar file as a dependency.

When I deploy the web application, it says that a class in the dependency of the jar file I created cannot be found.

The only way to work around this was to add the dependency of the jar file as a dependency of the war file.  This seems unnecessary.

Is there a way I can configure the war file to be able to see the classes defined in a dependency of a dependent jar file?

my jar pom file looks like: The dependency that has the class that can't be found is the the QRS one.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.7</version>
<name>name</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group2</groupId>
        <artifactId>QRS</artifactId>
        <version>8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

my war pom looks like:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the war plug in is configured:

```
          <plugin>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.name}-${project.version}-${env}</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <include>jboss-web.xml</include>
                        <include>web.xml</include>
                        <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <warSourceExcludes>**/toAggregateAndRemove/**</warSourceExcludes>
                <goal>war:manifest</goal>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven already resolves transitive dependencies.

That it isn't indicates you're likely not doing it right: the other jar you've created should be a Maven project with its own pom, installed at least locally via `mvn install`, and listed as a dependency in the second project (the one that uses it).

The project using the jar only needs to specify that artifact as its dependency, the other project's dependencies will be transitively determined and included as a project dependency.

Comment: The other jar is a maven project with its own pom and pulled into my local respository and is listed as a dependency of the war file and lists the transitive dependency as a dependency

The war file just lists the jar file as a dependency and not the transitive dependency.

Comment: @Eric How/what are you deploying? Maven won't magically create an uber-jar with all other classes (besides your own) in it unless you tell it to. You can also use Maven to copy the project dependencies into a directory, for example, to include them in a tar file. Otherwise a compile-time dependency is just that--a compile-time dependency.

Comment: i'm deploying a war file to jboss.

I have maven copying the dependencies of the jar file into the actual jar file.

When i view the jar file in the web project, I see all the dependent jar files, including the one with the missing class.

It compiles fine, it just won't deploy becuase spring tries to instanciate the beans and can't because it can't find the class in the dependency of the dependency

Comment: @Eric Then you'll need to edit your question with further information about the pom of the web app, perhaps some of the dependency's pom, etc. You're not really providing very much to go on other than "it doesn't work". You can also use the `dependency` plugin to see what Maven thinks your dependency tree looks like; `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @Eric You shouldn't need to be doing manual dependency management for your war; creating a `war` artifact does this for you. If *all* dependencies are located in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory, however, this has absolutely nothing to do with Maven, obviously.

Comment: I've added the relevant pom file snippets

Comment: @Eric Is the web app project defined as `war` packaging? Are the jars actually located in `WEB-INF/lib` in the war file? If so, again, not a Maven issue--if the libraries are in the right place in the war, something else is wrong.

Comment: yes and yes  But of course the transitive dependency is not in the lib dir of the war.  However it is in the packaged jar file that is in the lib dir.

Comment: @Eric I don't understand what your saying. If the transitive dependency is a jar file, it *shouldn't* be in a jar file, it already *is* a jar file, and should be in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. If the class file the container says is missing is a class, and in a jar in `WEB-INF/lib` then again, this has nothing to do with Maven, but some other classpath issue related to your container.

Comment: sorry, let me clarify
The transitive dependency is a jar file, as you said.  It is packaged in the parent jar file's lib directory.  Then the parent jar is packaged in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the war file.

You may be right that it might be a class path issue. However, how do I configure my class path to reference a class that exists within a dependency of a jar file?

Comment: @Eric You can't nest jar files like that and expect a web container to locate it unless you're using a custom classloader. IMO if things are working correctly, however, if the "lowest level" jar is specified as a dependency of the "middle" jar, and the "middle" jar is a dependency of the web app, I don't know why it wouldn't work anyway. If you can reproduce the issue in new, minimal projects and put them in github I'll try to take a look.

Comment: I'm picking this up again because I noticed something different recently that might explain why the transitive dependencies aren't being pulled through.  My project is in groovy.  So I have a java based web app using a dependency that's in groovy that has dependencies that are in java.  It's the dependencies of the groovy project that aren't getting pulled in.

Comment: @Eric How are the dependencies being defined? If the dependencies are defined in Maven, Maven doesn't care what *language* it's in, all Maven cares about is the pom.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave Newton has answered, this should happen by default.

A few observations from the snippets in the question - if that helps...

- Packaging dependant jars as a folder of `artifact` project's jar.
- Defining the maven war plugin jar itself as a `dependency` for maven war plugin - this is not required at all!
- `war:manifest` goal in the maven war plugin configuration.

It is possible that the `war:war` which actually creates the war is not run.